# How to tell Ivy to use completing-read-default for specific command? (org-tags-view, in particular)

Tags: org-mode, completion, ivy, completing-read

Ivy (+swiper +counsel) is very cool and I use it constantly for an ever growing number of tasks. But there are some cases in which the requirements of a certain completion task defeats Ivy's logic. One of those is Org tags search, more precisely, `org-tags-view` which is commonly bound to `C-c a m`. And this command conflicts with Ivy's logic both because it requires (typically) multiple candidates, and is supposed to output a single string out of them, connected by plus or minus signs. So a typical case would be "+tag1+tag2-tag3".

The default completion works better in this case, and while using Ivy, I'd like to tell it to use default completion in this particular function. Theoretically, there is already a `defcustom` meant for this task: `ivy-completing-read-handlers-alist`. But I cannot get it to work with `org-tags-view`.

I've tried:

```
(add-to-list 'ivy-completing-read-handlers-alist
             '(org-tags-view . completing-read-default))
```

But also, as `org-tags-view` calls `org-make-tags-matcher` internally:

```
(add-to-list 'ivy-completing-read-handlers-alist
             '(org-make-tags-matcher . completing-read-default))
```

Neither inhibited Ivy completion from kicking in. Does anyone know what I may be missing? Or how to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you executed the code? I just tried:

```
(push  '(org-tags-view . completing-read-default)
   ivy-completing-read-handlers-alist)
```

and it worked as expected.

**Responding to the comment:**

Indeed when calling it from `org-agenda` it does not work. As you supposed, this is because `this-command` is changed to `org-agenda`. As you probably don't want affect other commands called from agenda I would recommend to advice `org-tags-view`.

There are different ways you could achieve what you want, by let binding `this-command` or `ivy-completing-read-handlers-alist`. One that does not depend on `ivy` (so continues to work should you switch the completing framework some day) is:

```
(define-advice org-tags-view (:around (f &rest args) use-completing-read-default)
  (let ((completing-read-function #'completing-read-default)
        (completion-in-region-function #'completion--in-region))
    (apply f args)))
```

Comment: clemera, thank you very much for your comment. I think it made me understand the problem. First, yes, I was executing the code, and checked the variable. But I believe the issue is *how* I was accessing `org-tags-view`. Indeed, if I call the command directly, the setting works. But not so if I do it from the agenda dispatcher. Probably what is happening is that `ivy-completing-read-handlers-alist` is testing for `this-command` and, in this case, it is `org-agenda` rather than `org-tags-view`. Do you have any idea on how to deal with that?

Comment: @gusbrs I updated the answer, explaining how to work around that.

Comment: clemera, thanks again. Since I asked, I had tried, among a number of things, to advise `org-tags-view` let binding `completing-read-function`. In my attempts, and in your proposed advice too, Ivy doesn't kick in at first, but in the end does so, once you press TAB. I couldn't figure out, but there is probably some recursion in the process. The only way I could make it work was really with an advice around `org-tags-view` which disabled `ivy-mode` before running the function and then reenabled it afterwards. [...]

Comment: [...] Though I think a technically correct solution to this would indeed involve not tampering with any other agenda commands besides `org-tags-view` (your thought was the same as mine in the matter), in practice, all other default commands in the agenda dispatcher do not require completion. In my case, none of my custom ones require it either. So I ended up adding `org-agenda` to `ivy-completing-read-handlers-alist`, which I think was the cleanest solution given my settings. So I'll accept your answer for having taken me to the right place. Thank you very much!

Comment: @gusbrs The reason that ivy kicks in when you press TAB in that menu is because TAB is bound to `minibuffer-complete` which in turn calls `completion-in-region`. I will update the answer to cover that case as well.

Comment: Ah!, I hadn't been introduced to `completion-in-region-function`! Now it works perfectly. Thank you yet again.

Comment: @gusbrs `completion-in-region-function` is used for in buffer completion (usually code completion or as in your case completing input in minibuffer). `completing-read-function` is used for completing against a set of items (buffers, tags ...). You are welcome!